# UISegmentedControl to control segues

Tags: ios, segue, uisegmentedcontrol

Hi I am creating an application which will switch between bluetooth and wifi mode. I want to use a UISegmentedControl to switch between the segues. The photo album I will post is an example of what I want to achieve, although that was done with .xibs. 
I've already tried using the IBAction method for the segment and then using the performSegueWithIdentifier method. The latter only works one way and not vice-versa, which is what I need. Also even though it works for one way, I still get an error.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vzb22.jpg

To clarify I want to be able to toggle between the two screens, but I am only able to switch from screen 1 to 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two different segues, and you want to perform one based on what was pressed then just check which index is selected and perform that segue:

```
- (IBAction)yourSegmentedControlPressed:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex==0)//left control button pressed
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourFirstSegue" sender:self];
    }
    else if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex==1)//right control button pressed
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSecondSegue" sender:self];
    }
}
```

If you want to use another button to control the segues, then simply just grab the segmentedControl outlet and check the index inside of that action. NOTE: the index will be equal to -1 if neither is selected.

Comment: As a side note though: based on your attached image, I would not be segueing between views. You should just modify the current view depending on which is selected.

Comment: ^That's what I wanted to do, just didn't know it was possible. Any help to get started?

Comment: Is your other view just going to contain two textfields and labels as well?

Comment: One label and one text field.

Comment: Okay just set a bool to signify which state your in and thus u can reuse the same textfield but save the values in different properties. Set the unused label and textfield hidden when you change views. Change the UILabel to reflect whatever is relevant for each view. Hope this helps!

Comment: Initially I tried two separate views but that got confusing as one view got layered onto another, I'll try your implementation.